# Restrict results in google autocomplete API (not map js lib) by area bounds

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I know we can restrict results from autocomplete by country

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete

But is it possible to restrict it by area bounds too? this can be done in js lib.

But what about the api? I am trying to restrict results in my android app

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `radius` in the documentions paragraph `optional parameters`:

> - radius — The distance (in meters) within which to return place results. Note that setting a radius biases results to the indicated
>     area, but may not fully restrict results to the specified area. See
>     [Location Biasing](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete#location_biasing) below.